# What's the Hex or RGB color for these buttons

Tags: color, color-conversion, rgb, hex

I've been trying to find the hex rgb color code for color being used for [these](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/blank-darkblue-web-buttons-website-app-105881567) buttons. Specifically, the very firts button with rounded corners. I've been searching colorswall.com or other similar sites but have not been able to find the hex or rgb color code. What is rgb or hex code for it? Thank you.

Comment: a) which part of it? b) what prevents you from determining this yourself?

Comment: As I scan through all the shades of color I mostly see different shades that don't match exactly. For example, there are different shades of blue grey and blue violet but none are the same color as the buttons.

Comment: Don't you have access to any kind of 'hover over' colour meter? There's one built-into macOS, presumably other OSes have something similar, or one can be obtained.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Use the Eyedropper tool (aka colour picker tool) to sample the colours. Most graphics software has this.  Photoshop, Illustrator, Inkscape (free), GIMP (free), Krita (free) etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't find a particular color code that looks like the button is because it's all gradients.  The average color is around #15597d.

If you want to recreate the button, notice how it's made - a blue gradient going from top to bottom, and a scaled version of the shape on top with a transparent fading white gradient.  Use a color picker to get the top and bottom of the gradient and emulate it as close as possible.  Looks like the top is RGB 18, 34, 69 and the bottom is 0, 106, 140.

Edit: FYI, if you have Photoshop, you can easily get the hex code for a color by clicking the swatch in your tool panel.  It's displayed in the lower right corner.